# Разделить длинную строку по 200 символов

Tags: python

У меня есть длинная строка, как я могу разделить ее по 200 символов, пытаюсь в конечном результате получить массив. Сейчас делаю таким образом

```
x = "длинная строка"
spl = [x[i:i+200] for i in range(0, len(x), 200)]
```

возможно есть более удачное решение, или библиотека?

Comment: более удачное по времени выполнения, расходу памяти, другим параметрам ?

Comment: просто хочу рассмотреть все возможные решения поставленной задачи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это сэкономит время (в некотором смысле) и память, т.к. создается генератор, а не целиком список, но также лишит вас возможности обращаться к элементам по индексу (`spl[i]`):
`spl = (x[i:i+200] for i in range(0, len(x), 200))`.

Эквивалент в функции-генераторе:

```
def split_by_count(string):
    for i in range(0, len(string), 200):
        yield x[i:i+200]
```

"Универсализация":

```
def split_by_count(string, start=0, count=1):
    for i in range(start, len(string), count):
        yield string[i:i+count]
```

---

По поводе библиотеки: сомневаюсь, что есть библиотека, которая просто разделяет строку по 200 символов, да и этот функционал, как вы уже видите, реализуется слишком уж просто, чтобы выносить его в отдельную функцию.

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение `r'.{1,200}'`, будет захватывать любые символы от 1 до 200 штук (кроме переноса строки). Добавить флажок `re.DOTALL` — начнет находить перенос строки включительно. А `re.findall()` сразу возвращает массив совпадений.

```
import re

x = "длинная строка"

def cut(x, chunk = 200):
    return re.findall(r'.{1,' + str(chunk) + '}', x, re.DOTALL)

print( cut(x, 5) ) # ['длинн', 'ая ст', 'рока']
```

Другой вариант: Сразу выделить массив нужного размера и циклом добавлять символы к нужным элементам:

```
x = "длинная строка"

def cut(x, chunk = 200):
    i = 0; result = [""] * (len(x) // chunk + bool(len(x) % chunk))
    #        а-ля math.ceil(len(x) / chunk)

    for char in x:
        result[i // chunk] += char
        i += 1

    return result

print( cut(x, 5) ) # ['длинн', 'ая ст', 'рока']
```